# How to implement the Lispian cond macro?

Tags: macros, rust, rust-macros

Intended usage:

```
cond! {
  x > 5 => 0,
  x < 3 => 1,
  true => -1
}
```

Should expand to:

```
if x > 5 { 0 } else if x < 3 { 1 } else if true { -1 }
```

Note that it doesn't produce a catch-all `else { ... }` suffix.

My attempt:

```
macro_rules! cond(
    ($pred:expr => $body:expr) => {{
        if $pred {$body}
    }};
    ($pred:expr => $body:expr, $($preds:expr => $bodies:expr),+) => {{
        cond! { $pred => $body } else cond! { $($preds => $bodies),+ }
    }};
);
```

However, the compiler complains about the `else` keyword.

```
error: expected expression, found keyword `else`
  --> src/main.rs:32:34
   |
32 |           cond! { $pred => $body } else cond! { $($preds => $bodies),+ }
   |                                    ^^^^
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Macros in Rust don't perform textual substitution like the C preprocessor does. Moreover, the result of a macro is already "parsed", so you can't just append something after the macro invocation that's supposed to be part of what the macro expands to.

In your case, you can't put an `else` after the first `cond!` invocation because the compiler has already finished parsing the `if` expression; you need to put the `if` and the `else` together. Likewise, when you invoke `cond!` again after the `else`, you need to add braces around the call, because the sequence `else if` does not begin a nested `if` expression.

```
macro_rules! cond {
    ($pred:expr => $body:expr) => {
        if $pred { $body }
    };
    ($pred:expr => $body:expr, $($preds:expr => $bodies:expr),+) => {
        if $pred { $body } else { cond! { $($preds => $bodies),+ } }
    };
}
```

Ultimately though, this macro is pretty much useless. An `if` expression without an `else` clause always has its type inferred to be `()`, so unless all the branches evaluate to `()` (or diverge), the expanded macro will produce type mismatch errors.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this.